# Construct a non Lebesgue measurable function with given condition.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Construct a function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$, which is not Lebesgue measurable, but $f^{−1}(\{x\})$ is Lebesgue  measurable for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.